# React SetState and dispatch not working onClick function

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-redux, state

I hope that some one helps me  i get Content-Range from server and transform the string to the pagination

For example : when i call

> sitesActions.getAll()

**My action returns**

```
 sites:
  acceptRange:"10"
  contentRange:"0-9/25"
  data:(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}..]
```

> Content-Range : 0-9/25
>
> Accept-Range : 10 (The maximum collection returned)

These result makes me generate my pagination array  like this example

**Pagination Details function generate array of pagination**

```
function paginationDetails(contentRange, acceptRange) {

    console.log('content', contentRange);
    let paginationDetails = contentRange.split("/");
    let allCollection = parseInt(paginationDetails[1]);
    let numberReturnedData = acceptRange;
    let paginationNbr = Math.ceil(allCollection/numberReturnedData);
    let rows = [{
        pageNumber : 1 ,
        startData : 0,
        endData:  numberReturnedData-1
    }]

    for (let i = 1; i < paginationNbr; i++) {
        let end = (numberReturnedData-1)+(Number(i)*numberReturnedData);
            rows.push(
                {
                    pageNumber: Number(i)+1, 
                    startData : numberReturnedData*Number(i), 
                    endData: (end>allCollection) ? allCollection : end ,
                }

            );
    }
    console.log(rows);
    return rows;
}
```

**Array of pagination**

> [{pageNumber: 1, startData: 0, endData: 9}
>
> {pageNumber: 2, startData: 10, endData: 19}
>
> {pageNumber: 3, startData: 20, endData: 25}]

To make the pagination Componenet Global and reused in each component
i add to my parent component **click={sitesActions.getAllWithRange}**

**Action Get all with range**

```
function getAllWithRange(start, end) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request());
        sitesService.rangeSites(start, end)
            .then(
                sites => dispatch(success(sites)),
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error('Error fetching site data'));
                }
            );
    };

    function request() { return { type: sitesConstants.SITES_REQUEST } }
    function success(sites) { return { type: sitesConstants.SITES_SUCCESS, sites } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: sitesConstants.SITES_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

so i dispatch this props and uses it in pagination using

```
dispatch(this.props.click(elementInfo.startData, elementInfo.endData));
```

**Pagination Component**

```
<PaginationManager
        click={sitesActions.getAllWithRange}
        paginationInfo={paginationDetails(sites.items.contentRange, sites.items.acceptRange)} />

        </Aux>
```

**Parent Component File**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Aux} from '../hoc';
import {paginationDetails} from '../helpers';
import { sitesActions } from '../actions/sitesActions';
import classes from './BillsManager.css';
import PaginationManager from './PaginationManager';


class SitesManager extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(sitesActions.getAll());
    }

    goToSite(siteLink) {
            window.open('http://'+siteLink, '_blank');
    }

    render(){
        const { sites } = this.props;

        return(
        <Aux>
            <h1>Sites</h1>
            <p>You can see all details of your sites.</p> 
            {sites.loading && <em>Loading sites...</em>}
            {sites.items && <Aux>
                <table className="table table-bordered">
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th>Site</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Renew</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                            {sites.items.data.map((site, index) =>
                                <tr key={site.id}>
                                    <th>{site.main_domain}</th>
                                    <th>{site.CreatedTime}</th>
                                    <th>{site.ps_status}</th>
                                    <th className={classes.Link} onClick={() =>this.goToSite(site.main_domain)}><i className='fa fa-globe'></i></th>
                                </tr>
                            )}
                </tbody>
                </table>

                <PaginationManager
                click={sitesActions.getAllWithRange}
                paginationInfo={paginationDetails(sites.items.contentRange, sites.items.acceptRange)} />

                </Aux>

            }

        </Aux>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) { 
    return {
        sites : state.sites 
    };
  }




export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SitesManager);
```

**Pagination Component File**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class PaginationManager extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            activePage : this.props.paginationInfo[0],
            activeIndex: 0
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick = (elementInfo, index)  => {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(this.props.click(elementInfo.startData, elementInfo.endData));
        this.setState({
            activePage : elementInfo,
            activeIndex: index
        })
    }

    render() {
        let isDisabledPrevious = (this.state.activeIndex === 0) ? 'disabled' : ''; 
        let isDisabledNext = (this.props.paginationInfo.length-1 === this.state.activeIndex) ? 'disabled' : ''; 

        return ( <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                 <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
                     <li className={`page-item ${isDisabledPrevious}`}>
                     <a className="page-link" 
                        onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.paginationInfo[this.state.activeIndex-1]
                        ,this.state.activeIndex-1)} >Previous</a>
                     </li>
                         {this.props.paginationInfo && this.props.paginationInfo.map((pageInfo, index) => {

                           return <li key={pageInfo.pageNumber} className={`page-item  ${(this.state.activePage.pageNumber === pageInfo.pageNumber) ? 'active' : ''}` }>
                                <a className="page-link"  onClick={() =>this.handleClick(pageInfo, index)} >{pageInfo.pageNumber}</a>
                             </li>
                             })
                         }
                       <li className={`page-item ${isDisabledNext}`}>
                       <a className="page-link" 
                        onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.paginationInfo[this.state.activeIndex+1]
                        ,this.state.activeIndex+1)} >Next</a>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
         </nav>);
     }
};


export default connect()(PaginationManager);
```

I was passing too much time trying to solve this problem , but i don't know why the setState don't work. The pagination works fine and the setState works and return the updated values just when i comment the `dispatch(this.props.click(elementInfo.startData, elementInfo.endData));`

Comment: There is a lot of code here.  Could you pare it down to create a MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for your reply i'l try resume more ;)  Updated : resume is done

Comment: does the console show any error?

Comment: no there is no error , but when i console.log the state it dosen't change